# How to write a blob data into a text file (i.e into CSV) and that should be restore back into the oracle database as a BLOB?

Tags: java, oracle, csv, blob, apache-metamodel

I am using `ApacheMetaModel` to `Extract` and `Restore` the data from `Oracle` database. I am `Extracting` data into `CSV` and `Restoring` the data back from `CSV` into database. Few Tables has an `Clob` and `Blob` data.

When `Extracting` the data from `Oracle`, I am converting `BLOB` into the `String` so it can be written into the text file (CSV).

```
Blob blob = (Blob) value; // blob value of oracle database  
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(blob.getBinaryStream());
insert.value(column, new String(bytes)); // insert into csv
```

`BLOB` (as a string) is being extracted successfully.

Now for restoring it back into database, I am doing the exactly the reverse

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes()); // read value from csv and convert it into the stream.
byte[] bytes = org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(stream); // convert stream to bytes
Blob blob = connection.createBlob(); // create a blob
blob.setBytes(1, bytes); // put bytes into the blob
insert.value(column, blob); // insert blob into database
```

When I am checking that restored data into the target database using `Oracle SQL Developer` it's showing me that data is corrupted.

`image could not be decoded from the binary stream`

**Please help me to Extract the BLOB data into CSV and restore back into the database from CSV.**

Comment: CSV can't store binary data, convert it to a text-safe format first, such as Base64.

Comment: @BoristheSpider `BLOB`

Comment: You cannot write arbitrary binary data to a text file! You need to, as @TimPietzcker says, encode to [Base 64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) first. Hex would also work.